# Is calling fit() supposed to keep the model's weights?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

At the moment, I'm using a custom generator which isn't written as a class, just as a function. To reset my generator and shuffle its contents for a new epoch I just have to call it again.

So, to train new epochs, I'm calling `model.fit()` after restarting my generators like this:

```
batches = 32
split_ratio = 0.8
epochs = 10
for i in range(epochs):
    train_set = dataset_generator(clean_path, noisy_path, denoised_path, noise_data, batch_size=batches, shuffle=True, 
                                  partition="training", split=True, split_size=split_ratio, seed= batches+i, 
                                  image_dimension = [256,256,3])
    valid_set = dataset_generator(clean_path, noisy_path, denoised_path, noise_data, batch_size=batches, shuffle=True, 
                                  partition="validation", split=True, split_size=split_ratio, seed= batches+i, 
                                  image_dimension = [256,256,3])
    model.fit(train_set, validation_data=valid_set, batch_size=batches, verbose=1, )
    model.save("./model_run" + str(i) + ".h5")
```

The problem is: the training is starting with accuracy 0 as if it was being trained from scratch. The keras output for the end of an epoch and the start of another:

```
#1st epoch:
757/Unknown - 754s 996ms/step - loss: 1.7376 - accuracy: 0.8544

#2nd epoch:
2/Unknown - 2s 919ms/step - loss: 1.5388 - accuracy: 0.6328
```

Isn't `fit()` supposed to keep the weights? What is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

You can customise the fit() method: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/customizing_what_happens_in_fit/

But I don’t think you should be generating a dataset and fitting every single epoch.

You need to define your own training loop for your TensorFlow model. I once called train(input_fn=) on my estimator. The train and input_fn methods contain the dataset unpacking and iteration for training. I found an example at https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/train_and_evaluate